# Программа отказывается работать при вводе большого числа

Tags: c++

Моя программа ищет простые числа в диапазоне `[2; n]`. При вводе `n < 65538` программа выполняет свою задачу за 4,5 секунды. Но при `n >= 65538` моя программа отказывается работать и завершается с кодом `-1073741819`. (Я заметил, что число 65538 близко к 2^16 (= 65536). Но, я думаю, это просто совпадение). Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
// Вывод всех простых чисел до n решетом Сундарама.
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n;

    cout << "Введите число n:" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    int k = (n - 2) / 2 + 1;

    bool* nums = new bool[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) nums[i] = true;

    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 1; i < k; i++)
    {
        int j = i;

        while (i + j + 2 * i * j < k)
        {
            nums[i + j + 2 * i * j] = false;
            j++;
        }
    }

    if (k > 2)
        cout << 2 << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i < k; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i])
        {
            cout << 2 * i + 1 << endl;
        }
    }
    
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    chrono::duration<float> duration = end - start;
    cout << "Длительность выполнения алгоритма: " << duration.count() << " секунд." << endl;

    delete[]nums;
    nums = NULL;

    system("pause>0");
}
```

Памяти может не хватило? Или в чём беда?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предельные значения переменной типа `int` равны -2147483648 .. +2147483647 . Превышение можно достичь при индексах 32768. Неопределённое поведение обычно приводит к отрицательным результатам.

```
32768 + 32768 + 2 * 32768 * 32768 = 2147549184 = -2147418112
```

что приводит к крушении программы при попытке модифицирования не своей памяти. Помогает использования типа побольше размера вроде `uint64_t`

Comment: "Неопределённое поведение обычно приводит к отрицательным результатам." немного неверное утверждение. Неопределенное поведение в результате вычисления выражения может приводить к любому результату, в том числе и к отрицательному

Comment: Не могли бы Вы написать, как считали ```2147549184``` в Вашем ответе? Я что-то не понял..

Comment: `unsigned int const x = 32768 + 32768 + 2 * 32768 * 32768 ; int const y = x ;` [GCC](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fKzo4anK7)